# Question about storing declaring variables in Python?

Tags: python

```
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset,steps=math.ceil(num_test_examples/32))
```

What does this python syntax mean?

Are both variables `test_loss` and `test_accuracy` now holding the value of `model.evaluate(....)`?

If you saw this code and you didn't understand the syntax what would be your method to figure it out?

Just start going through all the documentation until you stumble upon it?
Or
Ask Someone?

Comment: my method would be to work out what `evaluate` returns and then make some small tests to try out, did you try to do anything like that? i.e `x,y = 1,2`?

Comment: This is called _sequence unpacking_. You can find information about it in [section 5.3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of the python docs

Comment: What do you mean, "going through *all* the documentation"? Finding out everything you need about a specific function is trivial, if the library is decently well documented.

Comment: Seems like there must be a duplicate here, but this is explained in the [documentation for assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called `unpacking` and means that, if size matches, the values of the right side will be stored individually into the different variable of the right side

```
values = [1, 2]
a, b = values
print(a, "-", b)  # 1 - 2

values = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = values
print(a, "-", b, "-", c)  # 1 - 2 - 3
```

Here are the error you'll get if the size doesn't match

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
a, b = values       # ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

values = [1, 2]
a, b, c = values  # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

---

Using the `*` unpacking operator, you can also do these thing, to tell that the variable will take multiple values

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a, b, *c = values
print(a, "-", b, "-", c)  # 1 - 2 - [3, 4, 5, 6]

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a, *b, c = values
print(a, "-", b, "-", c)  # 1 - [2, 3, 4, 5] - 6

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
*a, b = values
print(a, "-", b)          # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - 6
```

---

The examples are made with `list`, that works with `tuple` too

Answer (score 0):

There are unpacking `model.evaluate` return tuple with to values

Easy example:

```py
list = ["value 1", "value 2"]

first_varible, second_varible = list
# Now first_varible contains first value from list and second_varible second
print(first_varible, second_varible)
# out: value 1 value 2
```